# si la propiedad (name) existe mostrar un error. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con un test que no logro resolverlo, lo e intentado de diferentes formas. y no logro identificar en que me equivoco.

---

como yo pensé el código:

1. agregar las propiedades a un Obj.
2. creo una condición, SI no existe la propiedad (name) entonces
   se va a agregar el newCat al array(cats) ya establecido.
3. si este se agrego correctamente, entonces devuelvo el obj que cree
   anteriormente.
4. recorro el array(cats) que tiene los gatos agregados y si tiene un gato con el mismo nombre, entonces mostrar un error ('El gato o gata ya existe').

```js
let cats = []
let accessories = []

module.exports = {

  testCats: () => cats,

  testAccessories: () => accessories,
      // Agrega un nuevo gato, verificando que no exista anteriormente su nombre.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <age> que inicialmente debe ser '1 year'.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <color> que inicialmente es un array vacío.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <accessories> que inicialmente es un array vacío.
      // El gato o gata debe guardarse como un objeto con el siguiente formato:
      // { name, age: '1 year', color: [], accessories: [] }
      // En caso exitoso debe retornar el objeto, osea el gato creado'.
      // En caso de haber un gato existente,
      // no se agrega y debe arrojar el Error ('El gato o gata ya existe') >> ver JS throw Error
      
//mi código:
      addCat: function (name) {
        let newCat = {
          name,
          age: '1 year',
          color: [],
          accessories: [],
        };
        
        if(!name){
          cats.push(newCat);
      }

//-------lo de abajo es lo que NO me funciona-------

        cats.forEach(cat => {
          if (cat.name) {
          throw new Error('El gato o gata ya existe')
          }
        })

//-------lo de arriba es lo que No me funciona-------
        return newCat;
      }
}
```

```js
//TESTING:
     it('Si el name del gato o gata ya existe, no se agrega a la lista y devuelve un error', function () {
        controller.addCat('Fifi', 'pink')
        controller.addCat('Bubbles', 'blue')
        expect(() => controller.addCat('Bubbles', 'red')).to.throw('El gato o gata ya existe')

      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que comparar dentro del bucle si el valor de la propiedad `name` de los gatos que existen es igual al valor de la variable `name` que la función recibió como parámetro. En ese mismo tenor, el nuevo gato debería crearse después que la verificación haya pasado, tú lo estás creando antes de verificar, haciéndote la ilusión de que esto verifica algo: `if(!name){` cuando eso lo único que hace es verificar que el parámetro `name` no sea nulo o false.

Así debería funcionar:

```
let cats = []
let accessories = []

module.exports = {

  testCats: () => cats,

  testAccessories: () => accessories,
      // Agrega un nuevo gato, verificando que no exista anteriormente su nombre.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <age> que inicialmente debe ser '1 year'.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <color> que inicialmente es un array vacío.
      // Debe tener una propiedad <accessories> que inicialmente es un array vacío.
      // El gato o gata debe guardarse como un objeto con el siguiente formato:
      // { name, age: '1 year', color: [], accessories: [] }
      // En caso exitoso debe retornar el objeto, osea el gato creado'.
      // En caso de haber un gato existente,
      // no se agrega y debe arrojar el Error ('El gato o gata ya existe') >> ver JS throw Error
      
//mi código:
      addCat: function (name) {
            
//-------lo de abajo es lo que NO me funciona-------

        cats.forEach(cat => {
          if (cat.name===name) {
          throw new Error('El gato o gata ya existe')
          }
        })

        let newCat = {
          name,
          age: '1 year',
          color: [],
          accessories: [],
        };
        cats.push(newCat);

//-------lo de arriba es lo que No me funciona-------
        return newCat;
      }
}
```